How to edit Software and Updates' options in shell file 22.04.05 lts
I am creating a shell script file to configure the Settings>About>Software Updates>Updates
The settings i want to set is

Subscribed to: Security updates only
Automatically check for updates: Never
when there are security updates: Display immediatelly
when there are other updates: Display every two weeks
Notify me of a new Ubuntu version: Never

I found some information about but its too old like for version 18, how i can configure these settings from shell file?

None of the other settings matter if "Automatically check for updates: Never". Are you SURE that you never want the system to never check for deb updates? Built-in automatic security updates are a popular feature.

@user535733 yes i am sure, it's not my decision but the leader of project i am working on.
because of "Automatically check for updates: Never" doesn't matter the others options? "when there are other updates: Display every two weeks" will not check every two weeks?
